# How to use ISession and Session Variable in same .cs file and pass Session variable inHttpHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, handler

I am trying to use a Session variable in my cs file, and in the same cs file i am using ISession.

Handler page..

```
int ImageID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Session["ImageId"]);
```

cs file...

```
    protected ISession Session
    {
        get { return Ioc.Resolve<IWebSessionManager>().CurrentSession; }
    }


     int ImagefId=objbal.GetImageID(Id);
     HttpContext.Current.Session["ImageId"] = ImagefId.ToString();
```

as i am going to next step while debugging I am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on Handler page.

and if I am trying to change in ISession Session name and HttpContext.Current.Session["ImageId"] to Session["ImageId"] then Session is showing the error Session does not exist in the currenct context.

Someone plz help me to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tell, did you make sure, you have inherited interfaces [IReadOnlySessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate.aspx) or [IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) in your Handler? According to [post](http://codes.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/23-Accessing-Session-Variable-in-HttpHandler-in-ASP-Net.aspx) on codedigest website *'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'* exception is thrown when Handler is not inherited from any of that interfaces.

Also did you make sure that state `"ImageId"` is added to session states with [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.add.aspx) method before it is accessed?